# build LXML. pre-compiled .c Cython files missing

Tags: python, lxml, cython

I must build lxml from source. `https://github.com/lxml/lxml`
As the file `/doc/build.txt` says, source code should be provided with pre-compiled .c files. Why I don't find them?  in `/src/lxml` there are only .pyx files. Where .c files are??

In fact I have the `lxml.etree.c` missing file during `python build` command.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misread build.txt. It says

> The lxml.etree and lxml.objectify modules are written in Cython_.
>   Since we distribute the Cython-generated .c files with lxml releases,
>   however, you do not need Cython to build lxml from the normal release
>   sources.

So you need to get "normal release sources" to have the C files pre-compiled, e.g. from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml. If you check out from git, you need Cython:

> *Only* if you are interested in building lxml from a checkout of the developer sources (e.g. to test a bug fix that has not been release
>   yet) or if you want to be an lxml developer, then you do need a
>   working Cython installation.

Comment: exactly! 'you do not need Cython to build lxml from the normal release sources'.  Isn't normal release sources that of git?   Anyway thanks for the link

Comment: No. "release" means "explicitly designated for consumption by users", as opposed to "only intended for contributors to the code of the project". Putting something into a git repository is *not* a release.